# How to set the length of ticks to be exactly 1 inch?

Tags: r

```
 x<-seq(-3,3,by=0.1)
 y=0.5*x^3 
 ## Set png size to be slightly bigger than plot to take account of one line margin
 png( "~/myplot.png" , width = 600 , height = 2600 ,units="px",res=100)
 ## Set graphical parameters to control the size of the plot area and the margins
 ## Set size of plot area to 6 inches wide by 15 inches tall
 par( pin = c(6,26) )
 ## Remove margins around plot area
 par( mai = c(0,0,0,0) )
 ## Remove outer margins around plot area
 par( omi = c(0,0,0,0) )
 ## Set y-axis take use entire width of plot area (6 inches) and to have 7 tick marks (-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3)
 par( xaxp = c(-3,3,7) )
 ## Set x-axis take use entire height of plot area (26 inches) and to have 27 tick marks (-13,-12,...,0,...11,12,13)
 par( yaxp = c(-13,13,27) )
 ## Create the plot
 plot( x , y , type = "l" , frame.plot = FALSE , axes = FALSE )
 axis( 1 , pos = 0 , at = seq( -3 , 3 , by = 1 ) , labels = seq( -3 , 3 , by = 1 ) )
 axis( 2 , pos = 0 , at = seq( -13 , 13 , by = 1 ) , labels = seq( -13 , 13 , by = 1 ) )
 text(0.5,5,expression(f(x)==frac(1,2)*x^3) )
 ## Turn PNG device off
 dev.off()
```

We can get the graph which is 6 inches width, 26 inches height, but the tick unit in the x-axis or y-axis is not 1 inch; please see the attachment g1.png:

[image]

The reason is R will not use the entire space to set the x-axis and y-axis, R keep little space; please see the attachment g2.png:

[image]

I can `png( "~/myplot.png" , width = 610 , height = 2700 ,units="px",res=100)`, but how can I make the physical length of tick unit just to be 1 inch?

Comment: Hi, I've removed one of your edits - if you would like to present a solution to the community, please do! but use the answer box below for that. And if you have an additional question, then please ask a new one (unless it is trivial and highly related, in which case ask the answerer below who helped you). Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To specify the exact settings you want it is best to output to PDF. The onscreen plot can change when it is re-sized etc. You need to set various graphical parameters to take care of the margins. There is a good outline of the plotting area in `base` graphics and the appropriate `par` names to adjust [**here**](http://research.stowers-institute.org/efg/R/Graphics/Basics/mar-oma/). This code should give you exactly what you asked for:

### Edit

It looks like the PDF device keeps a border of one line around the outside, no matter what. Be default line height ~ 0.2 inches. Therefore we increase our width and height by 0.5 inches and we get spacing of *exactly* one inch.

Here is the measurements on my computer!!
[image]

```
## Set pdf size to be slightly bigger than plot to take account of one line margin
pdf( "~/myplot.pdf" , width = 6.5 , height = 15.5 )

## Set graphical parameters to control the size of the plot area and the margins
## Set size of plot area to 6 inches wide by 15 inches tall
par( pin = c(6,15) )

## Remove margins around plot area
par( mai = c(0,0,0,0) )

## Remove outer margins around plot area
par( omi = c(0,0,0,0) )

## Set y-axis take use entire width of plot area (6 inches) and to have 7 tick marks (-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3)
par( yaxp = c(0,1,7) )

## Set x-axis take use entire height of plot area (15 inches) and to have 27 tick marks (-13,-12,...,0,...11,12,13)
par( xaxp = c(0,1,27) )

## Create the plot
plot( x , y , type = "l" , frame.plot = FALSE , axes = FALSE )
axis( 1 , pos = 0 , at = seq( -3 , 3 , by = 1 ) , labels = seq( -3 , 3 , by = 1 ) )
axis( 2 , pos = 0 , at = seq( -13 , 13 , by = 1 ) , labels = seq( -13 , 13 , by = 1 ) )
text(0.5,5,expression(f(x)==frac(1,2)*x^3) )

## Turn PDF device off
dev.off()
```

And the results:

[image]

Comment: how to make more labels in y axis?

Comment: i express my meaning wrong,now i edit the graph,make my meaning clear.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature so you want the x axis to be 6 inches in width in total and the y axis to be 15 inches in height in total? I currently have a 15 inch by 15 inch plot, with the y axis 13 inches in length (0.5 inches between tick marks) and the x axis 6 inches in length (1 inch between tick marks). Will this do?

Comment: ‘xaxp’ A vector of the form ‘c(x1, x2, n)’ giving the coordinates
of the extreme tick marks and the number of intervals between tick-marks when ‘par("xlog")’ is false. what is meaning of `0,and 1` in `xaxp = c(0,1,27)` ?i don't understand.

Comment: i revise my problem ,it is clear now ,How to set the physical length of tick unit to be 1 inche properly?.

Comment: last problem :the extreme left edge of the plot in the x-axis is -3 not 0,the extreme right edge of the plot in x-axis is 3 not 1.maybe it is `par( xaxp = c(-3,3,7) ) ` and `par( yaxp = c(-13,13,27) )` ??

Comment: @it_is_a_literature BUT the example plot which you put in your question, and you since removed (!!!) has an x-axis of -3 to 3 and uses x values of -3 to 3. Why would it be from 0 to 1? This doesn't make any sense. How would you display this plot if the x axis values were from 0 to 1? 0 and 1 in xaxp represent the fraction of the plotting area that the x-axis uses (0 is the left edge of the plot region and we set the x-axis to start there and take the value -3, and 1 is the rightmost edge of the plot region where x-axis ends and takes the value 3), `xaxp` has NOTHING to do with absolute values.