# How to draw pixel accurate plots in R

Tags: r, plot, pixel

I want to represent a matrix as an image, so I want to use the plot as if each pixel was a cell in the matrix. But for some reason I can't. First I've drawn on screen, where the resolution is in inches. So I changed to draw directly in a PNG image, where the resolution is specified in pixels, but the result is almost the same!

The following code

```
png(file="graf.png",width=1000,height=100)
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(NULL,xlim=c(1,1000),ylim=c(1,100))
for (i in 1:100) {
    p1 <- i
    range <- i
    p2 <- p1+range
    segments(p1,i,p2,i)
}
dev.off()
```

is giving me this image:

[image]

We can see there is a white margin above the black triangle, I think it shouldn't be there, since all heights are 100. And there is a black border around all the image, I think it shouldn't be there either. And the triangle ain't "smooth", the two sides should be completely straight, but there are "breaks" in some points, as if some "rounding" is going on somewhere. Why is that? And why the bottom angle of the triangle is so far from the corner of the image? The final image is 1000x100 pixels, after all!

One more thing: if possible, I'd prefer to draw the whole process on screen, where I can see it, and only in the end save it as PNG. (Unless direct PNG draw is much faster.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That border is the box around the plot you created. Because you set the margins to 0, the rest of the plot, i.e. axis ticks and labels are outside of the window. You can get rid of the box too by using `axes=F`. About the white lines near the bottom and top: by default, `plot` extends the limits a bit. To disable this, use `xaxs='i'` and `yaxs='i'`. You can find all this in `?par`.

```
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(NULL,xlim=c(1,1000),ylim=c(1,100), type='n', axes=F, yaxs='i',xaxs='i')
for (i in 1:100) {
  p1 <- i
  range <- i
  p2 <- p1+range
  segments(p1,i,p2,i)
}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Also easier to use `polygon(x=c(0,100,200,0),y=c(0,100,100,0),col=1)` instead of separate segments. Or `segments(x0=rep(0,100),x1=101:200,y0=rep(0,100),y1=rep(100,100),col=1)` if you really want segments ;)

Comment: Yes, thanks. But that is just a simplification of the real algorithm. Each line will be in a different place, simulating the distribution of some species. :) BTW, drawing in the screen to save later, is hard to get it right, because of inches imprecision? Or is not that complicated?

Comment: I usually start by drawing on the screen and then when I'm satisfied use `pdf()` or `tiff()` to draw plot to exact size. Perhaps [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298593/how-to-set-the-length-of-ticks-to-be-exactly-1-inch/16299712#16299712) is helpful.

Comment: This should do the trick: dev.new(width=1000,height=100,units="px",res=1). But dev.size("px") is returning 1088 x 108!

Comment: Don't get your last comment. If I call dev.new() to draw on screen, I need to draw it all again after I call png(), followed by dev.off(). Wouldn't it be easier and faster to draw on screen already on the right size, then only Save the image as...?

Comment: Would be easy, but I don't know how to draw on screen with the right size in _pixels_, only in _inches_. `tiff` and `png` plots can be specified in pixels, so that's why I use those to create a plot of the exact size. Not much extra work either.

Comment: The problem with png() is that I need a dev.off() to save it. But I want to make small changes and save a series of files. Any command like dev.save(), instead? Found it: dev.print() Think it'll do. Thanks!

Comment: Actually dev.print() says "can only print from a screen device". And if I use dev.off() all I've already drawn will disappear...